# Plotting standardised mel spectrograms

Tags: python, audio, librosa, spectrogram, acoustics

I'm trying to plot the mel-spectrogram of blast fishing sounds. The level of background sound is relatively similar across all recordings.

When I plot files with blasts the background sound shows as quiet, whereas in all files without this its much louder (see examples) - apologies I don't know the right terminology, would appreciate insight on this.

I suspect this is because the blast sound is a loud event which raises the amplitude of the file. How can I standardise this across all spectrograms so the background sound is at a similar amplitude (so the plot on the right looks like the one on the left)? e.g is there a parameter I can extract from a bomb file which I can use as a reference for all others.

```
# calculate mel features
audio, sr = librosa.load(path=audio_path, sr=sample_rate)
mels = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=file_1, sr=sr)
mels_db = librosa.power_to_db(S=mels, ref=1.0)
    
# plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.imshow(mels_db, interpolation='nearest', cmap='coolwarm', origin='lower')
ax.set_title('Mel spec')
plt.show()
```

Left = bomb, right = no bomb:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely issue here is the mapping of values to colors done by `imshow`. The default behavior is to automatically map the min and maximum values to 0.0-1.0 of the color map. Which is likely to be different between two separate spectrograms. To set the same intensity mapping, specify `vmin` and `vmax` in the call to *imshow*. You can set it to fixed values, or compute them from across all spectrograms you want to compare.

PS: you can get slightly nicer plots for spectrograms by using [librosa.display.specshow](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html). In particular, one can easily get the X axis to be time in seconds, and Y axis to be correct frequencies. For it to work correctly, one must specify the spectrogram parameters, such as `sr`, `hop_length`, et.c..

Comment: Had to use np.max()a nd np.min() on mels_db to get a ballpark valueto set vmin and vmax to, which I could then set to a range of my choosing that I got from one file and apply this to all others